# D3 is not rendering graph from an object list?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have been experiencing an issue with the following pieces of code. I have tried numerous things and searched high and low for the answer but to no avail. Here is the data I am trying to draw: https://gist.github.com/caffinatedmonkey/5714631

It is is the following format:

```
{
    "x":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    "y":[8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
}
```

It complies with the JSONLint validate tool so I'm pretty sure the data is not the issue.

The gist with the code is here: https://gist.github.com/caffinatedmonkey/5714631

In this application I have used the d3.v3.min.js javascript library. I was wondering how it would be possible to graph this data with D3 and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 works best when working with an array of objects. I would suggest restructuring your raw data so it looks like this:

```
[{x:1, y:2}, {x:2, y:100}, {x:3, y: 321}, ect}]
```

Right now,

```
.selectAll("li")
.data(data)
```

is joining each element of the data array to an 'li' element. Since data looks like this:

```
[
    "x":[1, 2, 3, ect], 
    "y:[2, 100, 321, ect]
]
```

there are only two elements to join, "x" and "y". When you try to look up each elements x property with

```
.text(function (d, i){
        console.log(d.x[i]);
```

it doesn't exist because 'd' is just an array.

Comment: Are You Sure there is no way to make it work without reformatting the data? The data in this format would almost double the file size!

Comment: How did you figure this out? Did you use a debugger? I'm new to D3. Thanks!

Comment: If you're concerned about the file size, I'd recommend creating a csv of the data (hard to show how that would look in a comment, but it isn't too complicated) and loading it with d3.csv client side to create a data structure identical to one I suggested above.

Comment: I've just read all the tutorials a couple of times and ran into the same problem. I didn't load anything into a debugger, but I'm 99% sure that the structure of your data is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since d3 works best with and array of objects it would be best to restructure the raw data. If restructuring the raw data is not an option you can do restructure the data on-the-fly at runtime. [The code in this fiddle should do the trick.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg394/)

If you don't want to change the data you can also use it as-is if you change some parts script. Instead of passing `data` to the `.data()` function pass `data.x` or `data.y`. If you do this you can look at the corresponding element by `data.x[i]` [Here is a fiddle demonstrating this.](http://jsfiddle.net/NLDdS/)